# Elasticsearch Query using list of strings in criteria. Nest 5.x

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using Elasticsearch 5.0.1, and I am running my code under .NET 4.5.2. I am using NEST 5.0 rc lib.

I have a class that contains a list of string.

```
public List<string> LastPagesViewed { get; set; }
```

I am mapping that clase using AutoMap like this:

```
.Mappings(m => m.Map<VisitorTest>(map => map.AutoMap()))
```

What I want to do is to query all the document that contains one or more urls on 'LastPagesViewed' property.

I am doing a search like this:

```
.Query(q => q
.Terms(c => c
    .Name("named_query")
    .Field(p => p.LastPagesViewed)
    .Terms(new List<string> { "url1", "url2" }))
```

But it is not working. I also tried to search only part of the url like "google" (if the url is http://www.google.com) but same result.

I tried this with a list of ints (instead of urls) and it is working, so what I am missing here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally got it!. The problem was that I did not take into account the analyzer impact when using term search. Once I change the query to use a match it all works as expected.

The new query will be like this:

```
.Query(q => q.Match(mq => mq.Field(p => p.LastPagesViewed.First()).Query("http://www.google.com")))
```

Comment: in your answer I dont see you pass a list of strings